# Font used for Timer in iOS 7's Clock app

Tags: ios, core-text, uifont, typography

I'm trying to create a `UIFont` instance that would give me a look of the font used for iOS 7's timer. The font is slightly thicker than vanilla *Helvetica Neue Ultra Light*:

[image]

Comment: Looks like `HelveticaNeue-Thin`

Comment: @jamapag It's somewhere between _UltraLight_ and _Thin_. I think it's the _UltraLight_ with some `UIFont` tweaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slight difference is probably due to some fractional offset of the text itself. The pixels in the two characters look very close to the same, but with different amounts of grey or black.

Try placing your Helvetica Neue Ultra Light text 0.5 pixels left or right and 0.5 up or down. You can fine-tune it with bigger or smaller fractions